# Highlighted words in LaTeX disappear in Pandoc

Tags: highlighting, pandoc, text, text-decorations

I wrote my thesis in LaTeX, but my supervisor wants a word document. So I used pandoc to convert it. Now I got my thesis back and had to mark the changes. I found this code (see below) to achieve this, using `\marker{..}` This also allows me to turn it off in the final version, without removing one-by-one the commands, just by simply setting `\proofreadfalse`.

However, now when I convert it to pandoc, using for example this code: `pandoc --standalone -f latex -s error.tex -o test.docx`  it just skips all the words which are marked yellow. How can I mark things in LaTeX such that pandoc understands this? I do not mind using another form of highlighting the changes, as long as I can keep using the `\marker{..}` command and can turn it off simply in the final version without removal of the commands

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex


\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}                 %example text

%highlighting text, if proofreadfalse then no highlighting
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\sethlcolor{yellow}
\newif\ifproofread
\newcommand{\marker}[1]{%
\ifproofread
\hl{#1}%
\else
#1%
\fi
}

\proofreadtrue
%\proofreadfalse


\begin{document}

When I convert this to .doc file using pandoc, it just skips the \marker{yellow marked} words... How can I make sure pandoc does keep it marker yellow?

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX]

[image: Word]

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Highlights are not represented in pandoc's AST so they are not converted. You can either write a [filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) or try [tex4ht](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht)

Comment: @DG' would it be possible to change the textcolor instead of highlighting? when I use \textcolor{red}{{#1}} instead I keep the word but it is not coloured

Comment: I can compile your document using `make4ht -f odt test.tex`. It even colors the text in yellow, but it is a bit unreadable. `\textcolor{red}` works better in this way.

Comment: @michal.h21 it worked for small texts, but not for my thesis. It gave multiple errors, I think make4ht did not like some of the commands I have in the thesis... Although pandoc and latex do not give an error, here it says multiple times that I need to put an extra } or forgotten \endgroup

Comment: @laylay could you please make a MWE for these errors? it is possible that it is caused by some package clash, or something similar that could be fixed relatively easily.

Comment: @michal.h21 I am afraid a MWE won't be it... it's a huge document consisting of multiple subfiles... I added a screenshot of the errors I receive in my original post

Comment: @laylay it seems to be related to images, it is probably caused by some clash in `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @michal.h21 I am using tikz in some cases, could that be it? And would there be a way to skip the parts (such as figures) that give an error?, so that I just have the text and then will edit the file to complement the missing stuff

Comment: @laylay TikZ should work, but it is possible that this is a package clash. You can use `\ifdefined\HCode\else ... \fi` for code that shouldn't be compiled with TeX4ht